# Removing the OneDrive Documents folder

Tags: windows, onedrive

OneDrive will frequently make a `Documents` folder, even when I keep deleting it.

I use the root OneDrive folder to store my files, so I have no need for this folder -- how can I remove it?

Additionally, just out of curiosity, a file that looks like `.XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX` (8 characters, 4 characters, 4 characters, 12 characters) will pop up in the same fashion as the Documents folder -- every once in a while, one I delete it.

What is this file and can I delete it?

I'm on w10, but this happened on w8, too.

Comment: Related: [*How to unlink my Documents folder from my OneDrive account?*](https://superuser.com/q/1205668/358766)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling One drive or completely hide it from file explorer?

Here’s how to use Registry Editor to turn off OneDrive everywhere completely:

Press Win + R keyboard accelerator to open Run dialog box.
Type RegEdit.exe and hit Enter or OK to open Registry Editor.
Navigate to the following registry key:
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows**

Right click on Windows and select **New -> Key**. Name the new key as OneDrive.
Note: If OneDrive key already exists, skip this step.

Right click on OneDrive registry key, and select New -> **DWORD (32-bit)** Value. Name the new value name as **DisableFileSyncNGSC**
Set the data for **DisableFileSyncNGSC** registry value as 1.

Credits

1. [Disable OneDrive Everywhere in Windows and Apps Completely](https://techjourney.net/disable-or-uninstall-onedrive-completely-in-windows-10/)

Answer (score 0):

I've read numerous resources online that it can't be done through an official approach, here are two workarounds for this issue:

1. Make the "Documents" folder hidden, and uncheck the "Hidden items" option:

   [image]

   [image]
2. Deselect the "Documents" folder from syncing:

   [image]

Choose whichever you prefer.