# Registry Editor is showing two Keys pointing to the same location Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-registry, onedrive

As the title suggests, I had to edit the registry keys in the following path due to some Onedrive issues. My Documents and Pictures folders could not be pointed to the local path. They were pointing to the folders created by Onedrive. So I followed the [answer of Stevosiak](https://superuser.com/a/1206452/1116241) and resolved the issue of not being able to get rid of the Onedrive folders.

However, now I have disabled backups for both of the folders in Onedrive and now it is showing me two Documents and Pictures folders have the same path when I checked the registry again out of curiosity. I am still able to understand why this is the case.

[Two folders have the same location paths as their data value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WixoL.png)

Comment: You just created a faulty registry key. Registry does NOT check for this.

Comment: @John thank you! Do I delete those entries then?

Comment: Also, what is the difference between `My Pictures` and only `Pictures`.

Comment: You can try but be very careful. Registry does not check for anything.

Comment: @John Thank you again. I will be careful.

Comment: @john it worked. Default registry values have been restored.

Comment: I can post an answer if you will find that helpful

Comment: @John I did! Everything is set and working as I wanted it to be.

Comment: @John, you should indeed post this as the answer and hopefully, the OP will give you credit for it. :)  Happy Holidays!

Comment: Thank you - answer posted.

Comment: @John Yes, the answer has been credited. I am using Windows for a long time so having a bit of trouble getting used to the file structure and functionality. Linux is still the OG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, now I have disabled backups for both of the folders in
> Onedrive and now it is showing me two Documents and Pictures folders
> have the same path when I checked the registry again out of curiosity.
> I am still able to understand why this is the case.

The process you followed has created a faulty registry key. Registry does *not* check for this.

If you can identify the keys, you can try deleting the duplicate key, but do be very careful. Registry does not check for anything.

Good luck with this.